# TabLayout with firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, tabs

can we implement tab layout on click so when we click any tab that it will update firestore recycler adapter with new data?
I have tried this

```
          day_picker.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    current_day = "secondSunday";
                    fetch("secondSunday");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fetch("secondMonday");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fetch("secondTuesday");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //TODO
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //TODO
                    break;
            
            }
        }

        
    });
```

the fetch method

```
    public void fetch(String CO) {

    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    Query query = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("lecture_table")
            .document("second") //change it to computer engineering collection for make it works for other universities
            .collection(CO).orderBy("priorty", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<lectures_table> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<lectures_table>()
            .setQuery(query, lectures_table.class)
            .build();

    lectureAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<lectures_table, MyLectureViewHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyLectureViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lecture_table, parent, false);
            return new MyLectureViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyLectureViewHolder holder, int position
                , @NonNull lectures_table model) {
            holder.lectureName.setText(model.getLecture_name());
            holder.time.setText(model.getTime());
            holder.class_code.setText(model.getClass_code());
            holder.class_code.setOnClickListener(v -> copythis(holder.class_code));
        }
    };


}
```

I want it whenever I click the tab a new data will be displayed in the recycle view

my database is like this

[image]

[image]

[image]

thanks.

Comment: Hi. can you please be little more specific what you want ? and what errors you are facing ?

Comment: when I click the tab nothing change, I've tried to send the collection path to the function but it doesn't work. only work when I send the collection path outside the TabLayout click Listener

Comment: @AppDev. I wish i was more specific

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo. Can you see it now

Comment: @NoamanMonther We need a screenshot from your database.

Comment: @AlexMamo Can you see it now

Comment: @AlexMamo 
previously I used this function but it works only for the first time on creat.
now the update that I want to do is when click Sunday retrieve data from Sunday and so on.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/noaman813/a15e2fadf74abc9bb7fb1ba7e480496f

Comment: I got as far as the fetch method. To narrow down the focus, can you please add comments to fetch method?

Comment: @MrTech I didn't understand

Comment: Can you add more comments to public void fetch(String CO) to follow along?