# Tablayout with firestoreRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-tablayout

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979230/tablayout-with-firestore) question but i think i wasn't very specified .
What i have . I have a DAYS paths in my DB . I was retrieving them using current day that i get from Calendar .
I want to improve it with tab layout so it shows the data of path sunday when I click sunday tab and so on.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post a new question just to provide more details for a previous post. You can simply [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63979230/edit), and it will get bumped to the top of the active queue.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks.